# Unity Ads Stuck in Loop

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a test ad setup in my unity game. I am calling the IntAd function from the GameManager Script after the game is over. But the problem is when I click the close button in the ad, the ad reappears again and again. Please help me how can stop IntAd function after showing the ad.

```
public class AdsManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static AdsManager instance;

    private string playStoreID = "000000";

    private string intAd = "video";
    private string rewardedAd = "rewardedVideo";
    private string bannerAd = "bannerAd";

    public bool isTargrtPlayStore;
    public bool isTestAd;

    public static int start;

    void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        InitializeAdvertisement();
    }

    private void InitializeAdvertisement()
    {
        if (isTargrtPlayStore)
        {
            Advertisement.Initialize(playStoreID, isTestAd);
            return;

        }
    }

    public void IntAd()
    {
        if (Advertisement.IsReady(intAd))
        {
            Advertisement.Show(intAd);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Here is GameManager Script-

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static GameManager instance;
    public bool gameOver;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null){
            instance = this;
        }
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        gameOver = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    public void StartGame()
    {
        UiManager.instance.GameStart();
        UiManager.instance.StartScore1();
        ScoreManager.instance.startScore();
        GameObject.Find("PlatformSpawner").GetComponent<PlatformSpawner>().StartSpawningPlatforms();
        //AdsManager.instance.BannerAd();
    }

    public void GameOver()
    {
        
        UiManager.instance.GameOver();
        
        ScoreManager.instance.stopScore();
        gameOver = true;
        AdsManager.instance.IntAd();
    }
}
```

code to call GameOver function

```
void Update()
    {
        if (!started)
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(speed, 0, 0);
                started = true;
                GameManager.instance.StartGame();
            }
        }

        if (!Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, 1f))
        {
            gameOver = true;
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, -25f, 0);

            Camera.main.GetComponent<CameraFollow>().gameOver = true;
            
            GameManager.instance.GameOver();
            

        }
```

Comment: Can't answer your question without seeing the code you have from your GameManager

Comment: Hi @GarrisonBecker GameManager script has been added

Comment: Can you provide the code that's calling the ```GameManager.GameOver()``` method?

Comment: Added in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have calling `GameManager.GameOver()` is inside of `Update()` so it's going to get called every frame, and if `!Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, 1f)` is always true when the game is over (and not just true once), then it'll end up calling `GameManager.GameOver()` every frame which lines up with the behaviour that you're seeing.

You could resolve this by adding `!gameOver` to your if statement, that way it'll only go into the if statement once at the end of your game, and then upon gamestart you could flip `gameOver` back to false.

```
        if (!Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, 1f) && !gameOver)
        {
            gameOver = true;
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, -25f, 0);

            Camera.main.GetComponent<CameraFollow>().gameOver = true;
            
            GameManager.instance.GameOver();
        }
```

Answer (score -3):

Just do an if statement with a bool named GameEnd. Set it to false. Play the ad only if GameEnd is false. Rite after the ad instantiates, set GameEnd to true.

```
    if (!Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, 1f))
    {
        bool GameEnd = false;
        gameOver = true;
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, -25f, 0);

        Camera.main.GetComponent<CameraFollow>().gameOver = true;
    
        if(! GameEnd)
        {
           GameManager.instance.GameOver();
           GameEnd = true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: If questions don't have enough information needed to accurately answered them, don't post answers until the information is provided.

Comment: GameManager script has been added

Comment: Just finished it try it now. Thanks for adding the script